# changing tabBarController Index from another viewController programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Short explanation.

I have a `ContainerViewController` that I'm pushing to a `navigationStack`.

The `ContainerViewController` has 2 child `UIViewController`. A `SlidePanelViewController` (a slide-out menu) and a `CenterViewController` (the content), my `CenterViewController` is a `UITabBarController` which currently has 2 `UIViewController`.

I have a button in my menu to that I need to change the `UIViewController` in my `tabBarController`. However nothing happens when I call my functions.

Here's the function I am trying to call:

```
func premiumFormulaTapGesture() {
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

(I also tried setting it to 0 and 2. Still with no results.) I tried putting `self.` in front of it without any luck.

I also tried putting it as a function in my `ContainerViewController`. But that didn't seem to work either.

Here's how I'm setting up my `UITabBarController`:

```
var centerTabBarController: UITabBarController!
```

in `ViewDidLoad()`:

```
let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
let suggestionsVC = mySuggestions_VC()
let testVC = detaiLSuggestion_VC()
let controllers = [suggestionsVC,testVC]
tabBarController.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: false)

centerViewController = tabBarController
view.addSubview(tabBarController.view)
addChildViewController(tabBarController)
```

my `tabBarController` does show up. And I am able to manually tap the 2 buttons on it, where it switches between the `viewControllers` as expected. I later plan on hiding the `UITabBarController`, and use the menu. The `UITabBarController` is going to be my method of changing `UIViewController` from the menu.

Also just to clarify. I'm not using storyboards.

Any help changing the `viewControllers` in my `tabBarController` would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you call `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1` what is `tabBarController`?  (I see that you have that variable name defined locally in `viewDidLoad` but what's it referring to in `premiumFormulaTapGesture`?)

Comment: You're completely right. I made a new tabBarController called menuTabBarController, defined it above the class. And changed my functions to menuTabBarController.selectedIndex = 1 and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much. If you want to go ahead and add an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phillip Mills didn't post an answer yet. So I'm just closing the open question.

My problem was that there was 2 UITabBarControllers named the same "tabBarController" after changing the name to "menuTabBarController" everything worked fine.

again thanks to Phillip Mills for solving my issue in the comments.